# Help with SQL totals and sums

Tags: sql, delphi, interbase

I have this SQL. Im not sure it is what i need, but it does select all the records i need. I just need to condense them now and total the counts and amounts for unique dates.

```
select m.account_tag, m.cmcl_forecast_cleared, m.check_amount,  
a.acct_id, a.acct_no, a.bank_id,  
b.bank_id, b.name  
from ap_master m   
join accounts a on a.acct_id=m.account_tag  
join banks b on b.bank_id=a.bank_id  
where m.cmcl_bank_cleared is null 
order by m.account_tag, m.cmcl_forecast_cleared
```

I only want to display four columns  Account, Date, Count, and sum

The account would be a.acct_no.
The date would all unique m.cmcl_forecast_cleared date for that account
The count would be total no of checks (records) for those unique dates (cmcl_forecast_cleared)
The sum would be the total check_amount for thos unique dates (cmcl_forecast_cleared)

I hope this is understandable. Im not sure if i need any grouping or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
  a.acct_no, m.cmcl_forecast_cleared, b.name,
  count(*) as TotalChecks,
  Sum(m.check_amount) as TotalAmount
from ap_master m   
join accounts a on a.acct_id=m.account_tag  
join banks b on b.bank_id=a.bank_id  
where m.cmcl_bank_cleared is null 
group by a.acct_no, m.cmcl_forecast_cleared, b.name
order by a.acct_no, m.cmcl_forecast_cleared, b.name
```

You group by as many columns as you need.

Comment: +1. Every time you need to combine an aggregate function with some other fields, you need to group by those other fields.

Comment: @Shane - in that case, just group by the b.name as well